# Code Golf: Collatz Conjecture

Tags: language-agnostic, code-golf, rosetta-stone, collatz

Inspired by http://xkcd.com/710/ here is a code golf for it.

**The Challenge**

Given a positive integer greater than 0, print out the hailstone sequence for that number.

**The Hailstone Sequence**

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) for more detail..

- If the number is even, divide it by two.
- If the number is odd, triple it and add one.

Repeat this with the number produced until it reaches 1. (if it continues after 1, it will go in an infinite loop of `1 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1...`)

Sometimes code is the best way to explain, so here is some from Wikipedia

```
function collatz(n)
  show n
  if n > 1
    if n is odd
      call collatz(3n + 1)
    else
      call collatz(n / 2)
```

This code works, but I am adding on an extra challenge. **The program must not be vulnerable to stack overflows**. So it must either use iteration or tail recursion.

Also, bonus points for if it can calculate big numbers and the language does not already have it implemented. (or if you reimplement big number support using fixed-length integers)

**Test case**

```
Number: 21
Results: 21 -> 64 -> 32 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1

Number: 3
Results: 3 -> 10 -> 5 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
```

Also, the code golf must include full user input and output.

Comment: I must have dedicated 500 hours in college trying to prove this damned thing.

Comment: Also see http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=14

Comment: *must not be vulnerable to stack overflows* : You should not have posted it here then! ;)

Comment: My friends stopped calling me, does that mean I solved the problem?

Comment: You're on SO, but once had friends?  ... what was that like?

Comment: Nice and simple golf. Maybe a bit too simple.

Comment: According to the wikipedia article, the Collatz *conjecture* is the statement that "this sequence terminates (reaches 1) for all natural numbers". Just to get the terminology right.

Comment: @Martinho, then edit my question.. I found the requirements hard to phrase as readable English..

Comment: The assembler answer is cool, but it's a bit **anti-code-golf** to select the *longest* answer!

Comment: FWIW (~0), of the inputs 1..1000, number 871 requires the greatest number of steps to reach the end - at 178 steps.  Extending the range to 100,000 took just under an hour, and reveals that 77031 requires 350 steps to terminate.  The biggest number processed is 1570824736 which itself requires 160 steps to terminate.

Comment: Is output to be formatted as shown here, on one line with " -> "? Or is one number per line acceptable (as many entries have)?

Comment: @MtnViewMark It doesn't matter, as long as you can clearly see each number

Answer (score 129):

### x86 assembly, 1337 characters

```
;
; To assemble and link this program, just run:
;
; >> $ nasm -f elf collatz.asm && gcc -o collatz collatz.o
;
; You can then enjoy its output by passing a number to it on the command line:
;
; >> $ ./collatz 123
; >> 123 --> 370 --> 185 --> 556 --> 278 --> 139 --> 418 --> 209 --> 628 --> 314
; >> --> 157 --> 472 --> 236 --> 118 --> 59 --> 178 --> 89 --> 268 --> 134 --> 67
; >> --> 202 --> 101 --> 304 --> 152 --> 76 --> 38 --> 19 --> 58 --> 29 --> 88
; >> --> 44 --> 22 --> 11 --> 34 --> 17 --> 52 --> 26 --> 13 --> 40 --> 20 --> 10
; >> --> 5 --> 16 --> 8 --> 4 --> 2 --> 1
; 
; There's even some error checking involved:
; >> $ ./collatz
; >> Usage: ./collatz NUMBER
;
section .text
global main
extern printf
extern atoi

main:

  cmp dword [esp+0x04], 2
  jne .usage

  mov ebx, [esp+0x08]
  push dword [ebx+0x04]
  call atoi
  add esp, 4

  cmp eax, 0
  je .usage

  mov ebx, eax
  push eax
  push msg

.loop:
  mov [esp+0x04], ebx
  call printf

  test ebx, 0x01
  jz .even

.odd:
  lea ebx, [1+ebx*2+ebx]
  jmp .loop

.even:

  shr ebx, 1
  cmp ebx, 1
  jne .loop

  push ebx
  push end
  call printf

  add esp, 16
  xor eax, eax
  ret

.usage:
  mov ebx, [esp+0x08]
  push dword [ebx+0x00]
  push usage
  call printf
  add esp, 8
  mov eax, 1
  ret

msg db "%d --> ", 0
end db "%d", 10, 0
usage db "Usage: %s NUMBER", 10, 0
```

Comment: x86 asm *and* 1337 chars.  I weep with joy.

Comment: I like the (ab)use of lea for 3n+1.

Comment: how do i complie in linux cant wait to try it

Answer (score 64):

### Befunge

```
&>:.:1-|
  >3*^ @
  |%2: <
 v>2/>+
```

Comment: You should read this in 2D. <>^v are arrows that change direction the "program counter" wanders. | and _ are conditionals that go up/down or left/right depending on whether the value on stack is true or false. The whole "code arena" wraps around through top-bottom and left-right.

Comment: And only 35 chars including whitespace! Not bad at all!

Comment: Are you sure it's not Perl?

Answer (score 51):

## Python - <strike>95</strike> <strike>64</strike> <strike>51</strike> 46 char

Obviously does not produce a stack overflow.

```
n=input()
while n>1:n=(n/2,n*3+1)[n%2];print n
```

Comment: You might want to specify Python 2.x.  IIRC, Python 3.x `input` doesn't do an `eval`.

Comment: This doesn't fulfil the requirements - it doesn't print the first number

Comment: why is this accepted? it's not the shortest one and it doesn't print the first number

Comment: I guess input() echoes the characters you type, so this does print the first number :)

Comment: @Danko: On a different line though.

Comment: You can print the first number for a cost of only 2 bytes by using `n=input()*2`

Answer (score 51):

**LOLCODE: 406 CHARAKTERZ**

```
HAI
BTW COLLATZ SOUNDZ JUS LULZ

CAN HAS STDIO?

I HAS A NUMBAR
BTW, I WANTS UR NUMBAR
GIMMEH NUMBAR

VISIBLE NUMBAR

IM IN YR SEQUENZ
  MOD OF NUMBAR AN 2
  BOTH SAEM IT AN 0, O RLY?
    YA RLY, NUMBAR R QUOSHUNT OF NUMBAR AN 2
    NO WAI, NUMBAR R SUM OF PRODUKT OF NUMBAR AN 3 AN 1
  OIC
  VISIBLE NUMBAR
  DIFFRINT 2 AN SMALLR OF 2 AN NUMBAR, O RLY?
    YA RLY, GTFO
  OIC
IM OUTTA YR SEQUENZ

KTHXBYE
```

TESTD UNDR [JUSTIN J. MEZA'S INTERPRETR](http://www.icanhaslolcode.org). KTHXBYE!

Answer (score 23):

### Haskell, 62 chars <strike>63</strike> <strike>76</strike> <strike>83</strike>, <strike>86</strike>, <strike>97</strike>, <strike>137</strike>

```
c 1=[1]
c n=n:c(div(n`mod`2*(5*n+2)+n)2)
main=readLn>>=print.c
```

User input, printed output, uses constant memory and stack, works with arbitrarily big integers.

[A sample run](http://bitbucket.org/mtnviewmark/haskell-playground/src/tip/StackOverflow/fun_output.txt) of this code, given an 80 digit number of all '1's (!) as input, is pretty fun to look at.

---

*Original, function only version:*

**Haskell 51 chars**

```
f n=n:[[],f([n`div`2,3*n+1]!!(n`mod`2))]!!(1`mod`n)
```

Who the @&^# needs conditionals, anyway?

(edit: I was being "clever" and used fix. Without it, the code dropped to 54 chars.
 edit2: dropped to 51 by factoring out `f()`)

Comment: After doing my Miranda post (which is basically just older Haskell), at least in Miranda you can cut that down by using just one exclamation mark each - f n=n:[[],[f(n div 2),f(3*n+1)]!(n mod 2)]!(1 mod n) - Works :)

Comment: Oh, yes, you're missing input and output.

Comment: @Martinho: Me too, but thanks to lazy evaluation, the tables are even *much cooler* than in other languages.

Comment: What about `(%)=mod;f n=n:[[],f([n`div`2,3*n+1]!!(n%2))]!!(1%n)`? Has same length but looks much cooler :P

Comment: An interesting approach is `f=(++[1]).takeWhile(>1).iterate(\n->[n`div`2,3*n+1]!!(n`mod`2))`, but unfortunately somewhat longer due to the verbose function names ;)

We definitely need some shortcuts ... `f=(++[1]).w(>1).i(\n->[n#2,3*n+1]!!(n%2))`

Comment: Using jleedev's idea: `c 1=[1];c n=n:(c$div(n`mod`2*(5*n+2)+n)2)` - 41 characters, this uses the fact that this is k*(3n+1)+(1-k)*n/2 where k=n mod 2

Comment: I added a new Haskell answer based on this code that does input/output. Since that increases the size to 97 characters, I didn't just edit this one. Would folks prefer that I edit my full answer into this one (preserving the votes, but upping the size) and delete my 2nd Haskell entry? Or should we keep them separate?

Comment: I deleted my other entry, and moved my code here, and incorporated yet more of the ideas from these comments. Increased to 76 characters, but does input and output.

Comment: Improved function definition and I/O character counts, for a total of 63 keystrokes.

Comment: Last edit lost a prior savings in the recursive call to c. I put it back and now we're down to 62!

Answer (score 23):

## Perl

I decided to be a little anticompetitive, and show how you would normally code such problem in Perl.
<sub>There is also a 46 (total) char code-golf entry at the end.</sub>

These first three examples all start out with this header.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use Modern::Perl;
# which is the same as these three lines:
# use 5.10.0;
# use strict;
# use warnings;

while( <> ){
  chomp;
  last unless $_;
  Collatz( $_ );
}
```

- Simple recursive version

  ```
  use Sub::Call::Recur;
  sub Collatz{
    my( $n ) = @_;
    $n += 0; # ensure that it is numeric
    die 'invalid value' unless $n > 0;
    die 'Integer values only' unless $n == int $n;
    say $n;
    given( $n ){
      when( 1 ){}
      when( $_ % 2 != 0 ){ # odd
        recur( 3 * $n + 1 );
      }
      default{ # even
        recur( $n / 2 );
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Simple iterative version

  ```
  sub Collatz{
    my( $n ) = @_;
    $n += 0; # ensure that it is numeric
    die 'invalid value' unless $n > 0;
    die 'Integer values only' unless $n == int $n;
    say $n;
    while( $n > 1 ){
      if( $n % 2 ){ # odd
        $n = 3 * $n + 1;
      } else { #even
        $n = $n / 2;
      }
      say $n;
    }
  }
  ```
- Optimized iterative version

  ```
  sub Collatz{
    my( $n ) = @_;
    $n += 0; # ensure that it is numeric
    die 'invalid value' unless $n > 0;
    die 'Integer values only' unless $n == int $n;
    #
    state @next;
    $next[1] //= 0; # sets $next[1] to 0 if it is undefined
    #
    # fill out @next until we get to a value we've already worked on
    until( defined $next[$n] ){
      say $n;
      #
      if( $n % 2 ){ # odd
        $next[$n] = 3 * $n + 1;
      } else { # even
        $next[$n] = $n / 2;
      }
      #
      $n = $next[$n];
    }
    say $n;
    # finish running until we get to 1
    say $n while $n = $next[$n];
  }
  ```

---

Now I'm going to show how you would do that last example with a version of Perl prior to v5.10.0

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while( <> ){
  chomp;
  last unless $_;
  Collatz( $_ );
}
{
  my @next = (0,0); # essentially the same as a state variable
  sub Collatz{
    my( $n ) = @_;
    $n += 0; # ensure that it is numeric
    die 'invalid value' unless $n > 0;

    # fill out @next until we get to a value we've already worked on
    until( $n == 1 or defined $next[$n] ){
      print $n, "\n";

      if( $n % 2 ){ # odd
        $next[$n] = 3 * $n + 1;
      } else { # even
        $next[$n] = $n / 2;
      }
      $n = $next[$n];
    }
    print $n, "\n";

    # finish running until we get to 1
    print $n, "\n" while $n = $next[$n];
  }
}
```

---

### Benchmark

First off the IO is always going to be the slow part. So if you actually benchmarked them as-is you should get about the same speed out of each one.

To test these then, I opened a file handle to `/dev/null` (`$null`), and edited every `say $n` to instead read `say {$null} $n`. This is to reduce the dependence on IO.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use Modern::Perl;
use autodie;

open our $null, '>', '/dev/null';

use Benchmark qw':all';

cmpthese( -10,
{
  Recursive => sub{ Collatz_r( 31 ) },
  Iterative => sub{ Collatz_i( 31 ) },
  Optimized => sub{ Collatz_o( 31 ) },
});

sub Collatz_r{
  ...
  say {$null} $n;
  ...
}
sub Collatz_i{
  ...
  say {$null} $n;
  ...
}
sub Collatz_o{
  ...
  say {$null} $n;
  ...
}
```

After having run it 10 times, here is a representative sample output:

```
            Rate Recursive Iterative Optimized
Recursive 1715/s        --      -27%      -46%
Iterative 2336/s       36%        --      -27%
Optimized 3187/s       86%       36%        --
```

---

Finally, a real code-golf entry:

```
perl -nlE'say;say$_=$_%2?3*$_+1:$_/2while$_>1'
```

46 chars total

If you don't need to print the starting value, you could remove 5 more characters.

```
perl -nE'say$_=$_%2?3*$_+1:$_/2while$_>1'
```

41 chars total
<sub>31 chars for the actual code portion, but the code won't work without the `-n` switch. So I include the entire example in my count.</sub>

Comment: Your optimized version, isn't.

Comment: @Motti These examples are **very** IO dependent. Having tested them multiple times, the optimized version **always** maintains a significant lead.

Comment: @Brad, when you run Collatz on one number then the optimization is a pessimization since no number should appear more than once (unless the conjecture is wrong). The reason you're seeing an improvement is that you're running many numbers (as in the Euler problem), in fact I wrote a blog post about this recently http://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2010/01/18/yet-another-meaningless-javascript-benchmark/

Comment: @Motti that's the optimization I was talking about. Also, in Perl `$i + 1` is **always** addition (response to the blog entry). Also using `Sub::Call::Recur` is also an optimization. Otherwise I would use `@_=$n;goto &Collatz`. (It is 10-20% slower if you change `state @next` to `my @next`

Comment: I believe perl golf stroke counting standards do not count the mandatory strokes for invoking the interpreter nor the quotes, but do count one for each flag beside E. Using those rules, your last entries count respectively 37 chars and 32 chars.

Comment: @Brad, regarding `$i + 1`, true, I mixed JavaScript up with Perl on this instance (forgot the `.` operator).

Comment: why didn't you just redirect stdout to /dev/null and print the times to stderr? i.e. `perl foo > /dev/null`, instead of changing your code.

Comment: $_=<>; would make it directly comparable to the winning Python answer (Perl golf being a somewhat esoteric sport), and still several characters smaller.

Answer (score 22):

### Golfscript : 20 chars

```
  ~{(}{3*).1&5*)/}/1+`
# 
# Usage: echo 21 | ruby golfscript.rb collatz.gs
```

This is equivalent to

```
stack<int> s;
s.push(21);
while (s.top() - 1) {
  int x = s.top();
  int numerator = x*3+1;
  int denominator = (numerator&1) * 5 + 1;
  s.push(numerator/denominator);
}
s.push(1);
return s;
```

Comment: "must include full user input and output"

Comment: @FX, replacing the `21` with `~` will cause the program to use a number from stdin

Comment: @gnibbler: Is Golfscript.rb updated? I got `(eval):1:in `initialize': undefined method `leftparen' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` when replacing `21` with `~`.

Comment: @KennyTM, Sadly GolfScript can't read stdin interactively you have to pipe something into stdin, like `echo 21 | ruby golfscript.rb collatz.gs`

Answer (score 19):

## bc 41 chars

I guess this kind of problems is what [`bc`](http://x-bc.sourceforge.net/man_bc.html) was invented for:

```
for(n=read();n>1;){if(n%2)n=n*6+2;n/=2;n}
```

Test:

```
bc1 -q collatz.bc
21
64
32
16
8
4
2
1
```

Proper code:

```
for(n=read();n>1;){if(n%2)n=n*3+1else n/=2;print n,"\n"}
```

`bc` handles numbers with up to **`INT_MAX` digits**

**Edit:** The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Experimental_evidence) mentions this conjecture has been checked for all values up to *20x2<sup>58</sup>* (aprox. *5.76e18*). This program:

```
c=0;for(n=2^20000+1;n>1;){if(n%2)n=n*6+2;n/=2;c+=1};n;c
```

tests *2<sup>20,000</sup>+1* (aprox. *3.98e6,020*) in *68* seconds, *144,404* cycles.

Comment: Change 'n!=1' to `n>1' for 54 chars.

Comment: Here's a command line for generating random arbitrary-length numbers for this entry (10000 digits in this case):  `cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9' | head -c 10000 | bc collatz-conjecture.bc`

Comment: @indiv - I had to test it :), it took 3 minutes and 12 seconds to process the 10,000 digits number. I saved the output to a file, it's about 1.2gb long, but yes it did finish correctly in 1. Point for `bc`

Answer (score 16):

### Perl : 31 chars

```
perl -nE 'say$_=$_%2?$_*3+1:$_/2while$_>1'
#         123456789 123456789 123456789 1234567
```

Edited to remove 2 unnecessary spaces.

Edited to remove 1 unnecessary space.

Comment: You can remove two unnecessary spaces (after say and after while)

Comment: Try

     perl -E 'say$_=10;say$_=$_%2?$_*3+1:$_/2 while$_>1'

Comment: I figured that the user would be aware of the starting number of the sequence ;-).

Comment: Sometimes when I come across base64 encoded text, I sometimes mistake it for Perl source code.

Comment: @Martin:I can't imagine how you'd do that. Base64 is *much* more readable.

Comment: Won't the extra `-n` flag count as a stroke?

Comment: 37 characters with "$_=<>;", which means it's not a command-line but a full program; still safely shorter than the winning Python answer.

Answer (score 15):

**MS Excel, 35 chars**

```
=IF(A1/2=ROUND(A1/2,0),A1/2,A1*3+1)
```

Taken straight from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture):

```
In cell A1, place the starting number.
In cell A2 enter this formula =IF(A1/2=ROUND(A1/2,0),A1/2,A1*3+1) 
Drag and copy the formula down until 4, 2, 1
```

It only took copy/pasting the formula 111 times to get the result for a starting number of 1000. ;)

Comment: I guess it's too late for me to point out that this is what the fill handle is for, huh? http://www.ehow.com/how_2284668_use-fill-handle-microsoft-excel.html :)

Comment: That's a pretty handy feature that I didn't even know existed. I just copied the first cell and then highlight all of the other cells and pasted once.

Comment: I learned about area-paste roughly ten years after i discovered the fill handle. figures.

Answer (score 14):

### C : 64 chars

```
main(x){for(scanf("%d",&x);x>=printf("%d,",x);x=x&1?3*x+1:x/2);}
```

#### With big integer support: 431 (necessary) chars

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define B (w>=m?d=realloc(d,m=m+m):0)
#define S(a,b)t=a,a=b,b=t
main(m,w,i,t){char*d=malloc(m=9);for(w=0;(i=getchar()+2)/10==5;)
B,d[w++]=i%10;for(i=0;i<w/2;i++)S(d[i],d[w-i-1]);for(;;w++){
while(w&&!d[w-1])w--;for(i=w+1;i--;)putchar(i?d[i-1]+48:10);if(
w==1&&*d==1)break;if(*d&1){for(i=w;i--;)d[i]*=3;*d+=1;}else{
for(i=w;i-->1;)d[i-1]+=d[i]%2*10,d[i]/=2;*d/=2;}B,d[w]=0;for(i=0
;i<w;i++)d[i+1]+=d[i]/10,d[i]%=10;}}
```

**Note**: Do not remove `#include <stdlib.h>` without at least prototyping malloc/realloc, as doing so will not be safe on 64-bit platforms (64-bit void* will be converted to 32-bit int).

This one hasn't been tested vigorously yet.  It could use some shortening as well.

---

Previous versions:

```
main(x){for(scanf("%d",&x);printf("%d,",x),x-1;x=x&1?3*x+1:x/2);} // 66
```

(removed 12 chars because no one follows the output format... :| )

Answer (score 12):

Another assembler version. This one is not limited to 32 bit numbers, it can handle numbers up to 10<sup>65534</sup> although the ".com" format MS-DOS uses is limited to 80 digit numbers. Written for A86 assembler and requires a Win-XP DOS box to run. Assembles to 180 bytes:

```
    mov ax,cs
    mov si,82h
    add ah,10h
    mov es,ax
    mov bh,0
    mov bl,byte ptr [80h]
    cmp bl,1
    jbe ret
    dec bl
    mov cx,bx
    dec bl
    xor di,di
 p1:lodsb
    sub al,'0'
    cmp al,10
    jae ret
    stosb
    loop p1
    xor bp,bp
    push es
    pop ds
 p2:cmp byte ptr ds:[bp],0
    jne p3
    inc bp
    jmp p2
    ret
 p3:lea si,[bp-1]
    cld
 p4:inc si
    mov dl,[si]
    add dl,'0'
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    cmp si,bx
    jne p4
    cmp bx,bp
    jne p5
    cmp byte ptr [bx],1
    je ret
 p5:mov dl,'-'
    mov ah,2
    int 21h
    mov dl,'>'
    int 21h
    test byte ptr [bx],1
    jz p10
    ;odd
    mov si,bx
    mov di,si
    mov dx,3
    dec bp
    std
 p6:lodsb
    mul dl
    add al,dh
    aam
    mov dh,ah
    stosb
    cmp si,bp
    jnz p6
    or dh,dh
    jz p7
    mov al,dh
    stosb
    dec bp
 p7:mov si,bx
    mov di,si
 p8:lodsb
    inc al
    xor ah,ah
    aaa
    stosb
    or ah,ah
    jz p9
    cmp si,bp
    jne p8
    mov al,1
    stosb
    jmp p2
 p9:inc bp
    jmp p2
    p10:mov si,bp
    mov di,bp
    xor ax,ax
p11:lodsb
    test ah,1
    jz p12
    add al,10
p12:mov ah,al
    shr al,1
    cmp di,bx
    stosb
    jne p11
    jmp p2
```

Answer (score 10):

## dc - 24 chars <strike>25</strike> <strike>28</strike>

[`dc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dc) is a good tool for this sequence:

```
?[d5*2+d2%*+2/pd1<L]dsLx
```

```
dc -f collatz.dc
21
64
32
16
8
4
2
1
```

Also 24 chars using the formula from the [Golfscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388254/code-golf-collatz-conjecture/2388910#2388910) entry:

```
?[3*1+d2%5*1+/pd1<L]dsLx
```

**57 chars** to meet the specs:

```
[Number: ]n?[Results: ]ndn[d5*2+d2%*+2/[ -> ]ndnd1<L]dsLx
```

```
dc -f collatz-spec.dc
Number: 3
Results: 3 -> 10 -> 5 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
```

Answer (score 9):

**Scheme: 72**

```
(define(c n)(if(= n 1)`(1)(cons n(if(odd? n)(c(+(* n 3)1))(c(/ n 2))))))
```

This uses recursion, but the calls are tail-recursive so I think they'll be optimized to iteration. In some quick testing, I haven't been able to find a number for which the stack overflows anyway. Just for example:

(c 9876543219999999999000011234567898888777766665555444433332222
7777777777777777777777777777777798797657657651234143375987342987
5398709812374982529830983743297432985230985739287023987532098579
058095873098753098370938753987)

...runs just fine. [that's all one number -- I've just broken it to fit on screen.]

Answer (score 8):

### Mathematica, 45 <del>50</del> chars

```
c=NestWhileList[If[OddQ@#,3#+1,#/2]&,#,#>1&]&
```

Comment: I counted 58 chars. And you can replace `OddQ[#]` with `OddQ@#` to save 1 char.

Comment: 50 characters: `c[n_]:=NestWhileList[If[OddQ@#,3#+1,#/2]&,n,#>1&]`

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby, 50 chars, no stack overflow

Basically a direct rip of [makapuf's Python solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388254/code-golf-collatz-conjecture/2388749#2388749):

```
def c(n)while n>1;n=n.odd?? n*3+1: n/2;p n end end
```

### Ruby, 45 chars, will overflow

Basically a direct rip of the code provided in the question:

```
def c(n)p n;n.odd?? c(3*n+1):c(n/2)if n>1 end
```

Comment: What version of Ruby is that? I get `n.odd??` not defined. Also, that is vulnerable to stack overflows with large numbers.

Comment: That's interesting. I have 1.8.7. Adding a space between the question marks should fix that. And you're right about the stack overflow. I'll edit my answer to make a note of that.

Comment: You can save four characters with `p n=[n/2,n*3+1][n%2]`

Answer (score 7):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class SortaJava {

    static final BigInteger THREE = new BigInteger("3");
    static final BigInteger TWO = new BigInteger("2");

    interface BiFunc<R, A, B> {
      R call(A a, B b);
    }

    interface Cons<A, B> {
      <R> R apply(BiFunc<R, A, B> func);
    }

    static class Collatz implements Cons<BigInteger, Collatz> {
      BigInteger value;
      public Collatz(BigInteger value) { this.value = value; }
      public <R> R apply(BiFunc<R, BigInteger, Collatz> func) {
        if(BigInteger.ONE.equals(value))
          return func.call(value, null);
        if(value.testBit(0))
          return func.call(value, new Collatz((value.multiply(THREE)).add(BigInteger.ONE)));
        return func.call(value, new Collatz(value.divide(TWO)));
      }
    }

    static class PrintAReturnB<A, B> implements BiFunc<B, A, B> {
      boolean first = true;
      public B call(A a, B b) {
        if(first)
          first = false;
        else
          System.out.print(" -> ");
        System.out.print(a);
        return b;
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      BiFunc<Collatz, BigInteger, Collatz> printer = new PrintAReturnB<BigInteger, Collatz>();
      Collatz collatz = new Collatz(new BigInteger(args[0]));
      while(collatz != null)
        collatz = collatz.apply(printer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Java: the language where you have to use BigIntegers just to count the number of characters in the code of the solution.

Comment: @Jared I totally agree that Java is verbose. You have to admit that the solution presented
a) meets the requirements 
b) is way longer than really necessary and 
c) plays with the java type system in a pleasing way

Answer (score 7):

**Python 45 Char**

Shaved a char off of makapuf's answer.

```
n=input()
while~-n:n=(n/2,n*3+1)[n%2];print n
```

Comment: very clever use of the ~ operator. I had to look it up to see what it did (I try to avoid binary operators in Python, so I', not very familiar with them).

Answer (score 5):

### TI-BASIC

Not the shortest, but a novel approach.  Certain to slow down considerably with large sequences, but it shouldn't overflow.

```
PROGRAM:COLLATZ
:ClrHome
:Input X
:Lbl 1
:While X≠1
:If X/2=int(X/2)
:Then
:Disp X/2→X
:Else
:Disp X*3+1→X
:End
:Goto 1
:End
```

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell : 50

```
c 1=[1];c n=n:(c$if odd n then 3*n+1 else n`div`2)
```

Comment: Using jkff's idea: `c 1=[1];c n=n:(c$[n`div`2,3*n+1]!!(n`mod`2))`, 44 chars

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby, 43 characters

bignum supported, with stack overflow susceptibility:

```
def c(n)p n;n%2>0?c(3*n+1):c(n/2)if n>1 end
```

...and 50 characters, bignum supported, without stack overflow:

```
def d(n)while n>1 do p n;n=n%2>0?3*n+1:n/2 end end
```

Kudos to Jordan.  I didn't know about 'p' as a replacement for puts.

Answer (score 4):

**C#: 216 Characters**

```
using C=System.Console;class P{static void Main(){var p="start:";System.Action<object> o=C.Write;o(p);ulong i;while(ulong.TryParse(C.ReadLine(),out i)){o(i);while(i > 1){i=i%2==0?i/2:i*3+1;o(" -> "+i);}o("\n"+p);}}}
```

in long form:

```
using C = System.Console;
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var p = "start:"; 
        System.Action<object> o = C.Write; 
        o(p); 
        ulong i; 
        while (ulong.TryParse(C.ReadLine(), out i))
        {
            o(i); 
            while (i > 1)
            {
                i = i % 2 == 0 ? i / 2 : i * 3 + 1; 
                o(" -> " + i);
            } 
            o("\n" + p);
        }
    }
}
```

**New Version, accepts one number as input provided through the command line, no input validation. <strike>173</strike> 154 characters.**

```
using System;class P{static void Main(string[]a){Action<object>o=Console.Write;var i=ulong.Parse(a[0]);o(i);while(i>1){i=i%2==0?i/2:i*3+1;o(" -> "+i);}}}
```

in long form:

```
using System;
class P
{
    static void Main(string[]a)
    {
        Action<object>o=Console.Write;
        var i=ulong.Parse(a[0]);
        o(i);
        while(i>1)
        {
            i=i%2==0?i/2:i*3+1;
            o(" -> "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to shave a few characters by ripping off the idea in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388254/code-golf-collatz-conjecture/2390396#2390396) to use a for loop rather than a while. 150 characters.

```
using System;class P{static void Main(string[]a){Action<object>o=Console.Write;for(var i=ulong.Parse(a[0]);i>1;i=i%2==0?i/2:i*3+1)o(i+" -> ");o(1);}}
```

Comment: You should mention your code accepts more than one input. Or take that away and shave off a few chars.

Comment: You could shorten Action<object> and possibly more to dynamic in C#4.

Comment: @Dykam: Just checked it: fails with "error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'Write' to non-delegate type 'dynamic'. Did you intend to invoke the method?".

Comment: Oh, ofcourse... implicit converting to delegates... requires denoting the delegate. Bummer...

Answer (score 4):

not the shortest, but an elegant clojure solution

```
(defn collatz [n]
 (print n "")
 (if (> n 1)
  (recur
   (if (odd? n)
    (inc (* 3 n))
    (/ n 2)))))
```

Answer (score 4):

**Scala + Scalaz**

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
val collatz = 
   (_:Int).iterate[Stream](a=>Seq(a/2,3*a+1)(a%2)).takeWhile(1<) // This line: 61 chars
```

And in action:

```
scala> collatz(7).toList
res15: List[Int] = List(7, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2)
```

**Scala 2.8**

```
val collatz = 
   Stream.iterate(_:Int)(a=>Seq(a/2,3*a+1)(a%2)).takeWhile(1<) :+ 1
```

This also includes the trailing 1.

```
scala> collatz(7)
res12: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(7, 22, 11, 34, 17, 52, 26, 13, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1)
```

With the following implicit

```
implicit def intToEven(i:Int) = new {
  def ~(even: Int=>Int, odd: Int=>Int) = { 
    if (i%2==0) { even(i) } else { odd(i) }
  }
}
```

this can be shortened to

```
val collatz = Stream.iterate(_:Int)(_~(_/2,3*_+1)).takeWhile(1<) :+ 1
```

**Edit - 58 characters**  (including input and output, but not including initial number)

```
var n=readInt;while(n>1){n=Seq(n/2,n*3+1)(n%2);println(n)}
```

Could be reduced by 2 if you don't need newlines...

Answer (score 4):

### nroff<sup>1</sup>

Run with `nroff -U hail.g`

```
.warn
.pl 1
.pso (printf "Enter a number: " 1>&2); read x; echo .nr x $x
.while \nx>1 \{\
.  ie \nx%2 .nr x \nx*3+1
.  el .nr x \nx/2
\nx
.\}
```

---

<sup>1. groff version</sup>

Comment: Scary!  Still, at least the output should be formatted nicely.

Comment: Hey, run it as `groff -U hail.g` and you get PostScript! :-)

Answer (score 3):

## F#, 90 characters

```
let c=Seq.unfold(function|n when n<=1->None|n when n%2=0->Some(n,n/2)|n->Some(n,(3*n)+1))

> c 21;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [21; 64; 32; 16; ...]
```

Or if you're not using F# interactive to display the result, 102 characters:

```
let c=Seq.unfold(function|n when n<=1->None|n when n%2=0->Some(n,n/2)|n->Some(n,(3*n)+1))>>printf"%A"
```

Answer (score 3):

Common Lisp, 141 characters:

```
(defun c ()
  (format t"Number: ")
  (loop for n = (read) then (if(oddp n)(+ 1 n n n)(/ n 2))
     until (= n 1)
     do (format t"~d -> "n))
  (format t"1~%"))
```

Test run:

```
Number: 171
171 -> 514 -> 257 -> 772 -> 386 -> 193 -> 580 -> 290 -> 145 -> 436 ->
218 -> 109 -> 328 -> 164 -> 82 -> 41 -> 124 -> 62 -> 31 -> 94 -> 47 ->
142 -> 71 -> 214 -> 107 -> 322 -> 161 -> 484 -> 242 -> 121 -> 364 ->
182 -> 91 -> 274 -> 137 -> 412 -> 206 -> 103 -> 310 -> 155 -> 466 ->
233 -> 700 -> 350 -> 175 -> 526 -> 263 -> 790 -> 395 -> 1186 -> 593 ->
1780 -> 890 -> 445 -> 1336 -> 668 -> 334 -> 167 -> 502 -> 251 -> 754 ->
377 -> 1132 -> 566 -> 283 -> 850 -> 425 -> 1276 -> 638 -> 319 ->
958 -> 479 -> 1438 -> 719 -> 2158 -> 1079 -> 3238 -> 1619 -> 4858 ->
2429 -> 7288 -> 3644 -> 1822 -> 911 -> 2734 -> 1367 -> 4102 -> 2051 ->
6154 -> 3077 -> 9232 -> 4616 -> 2308 -> 1154 -> 577 -> 1732 -> 866 ->
433 -> 1300 -> 650 -> 325 -> 976 -> 488 -> 244 -> 122 -> 61 -> 184 ->
92 -> 46 -> 23 -> 70 -> 35 -> 106 -> 53 -> 160 -> 80 -> 40 -> 20 ->
10 -> 5 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
```

Comment: Almost. There's no header for the 2nd line. I could've shaved 3 chars off ignoring the arrow, another 3-4 eliding unnecessary spaces, but I'm happy with a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 3):

**PHP**

```
function Collatz($n)
{
        $i = 0;
    while($n>1)
    {
        if($n % 2)
        {
            $n = (3*$n) + 1;
            $i++;
            echo "step $i:  $n <br/>";
        }

        else 
        {
            $n = $n/2;
            $i++;
            echo "step $i:  $n <br/>";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You're duplicating the `$i++;` and `echo "step ...";` twice. Move those after the else block to save some characters.

Answer (score 3):

The program frm Jerry Coffin has integer over flow, try this one:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(unsigned long long i)
{
    int j = 0;
    for(  std::cin>>i; i>1; i = i&1? i*3+1:i/2, ++j)
        std::cout<<i<<" -> ";

    std::cout<<"\n"<<j << " iterations\n";
}
```

tested with

The number less than 100 million with the longest total stopping time is 63,728,127, with 949 steps.

The number less than 1 billion with the longest total stopping time is 670,617,279, with 986 steps.

Comment: Any finite integer types cannot prevent integer overflow. Not even `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 3):

#### ruby, 43, possibly meeting the I/O requirement

---

Run with `ruby -n hail`

```
n=$_.to_i
(n=n%2>0?n*3+1: n/2
p n)while n>1
```

Answer (score 3):

### C# : 659 chars with BigInteger support

```
using System.Linq;using C=System.Console;class Program{static void Main(){var v=C.ReadLine();C.Write(v);while(v!="1"){C.Write("->");if(v[v.Length-1]%2==0){v=v.Aggregate(new{s="",o=0},(r,c)=>new{s=r.s+(char)((c-48)/2+r.o+48),o=(c%2)*5}).s.TrimStart('0');}else{var q=v.Reverse().Aggregate(new{s="",o=0},(r, c)=>new{s=(char)((c-48)*3+r.o+(c*3+r.o>153?c*3+r.o>163?28:38:48))+r.s,o=c*3+r.o>153?c*3+r.o>163?2:1:0});var t=(q.o+q.s).TrimStart('0').Reverse();var x=t.First();q=t.Skip(1).Aggregate(new{s=x>56?(x-57).ToString():(x-47).ToString(),o=x>56?1:0},(r,c)=>new{s=(char)(c-48+r.o+(c+r.o>57?38:48))+r.s,o=c+r.o>57?1:0});v=(q.o+q.s).TrimStart('0');}C.Write(v);}}}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
using System.Linq;
using C = System.Console;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var v = C.ReadLine();
        C.Write(v);
        while (v != "1")
        {
            C.Write("->");
            if (v[v.Length - 1] % 2 == 0)
            {
                v = v
                    .Aggregate(
                        new { s = "", o = 0 }, 
                        (r, c) => new { s = r.s + (char)((c - 48) / 2 + r.o + 48), o = (c % 2) * 5 })
                    .s.TrimStart('0');
            }
            else
            {
                var q = v
                    .Reverse()
                    .Aggregate(
                        new { s = "", o = 0 }, 
                        (r, c) => new { s = (char)((c - 48) * 3 + r.o + (c * 3 + r.o > 153 ? c * 3 + r.o > 163 ? 28 : 38 : 48)) + r.s, o = c * 3 + r.o > 153 ? c * 3 + r.o > 163 ? 2 : 1 : 0 });
                var t = (q.o + q.s)
                    .TrimStart('0')
                    .Reverse();
                var x = t.First();
                q = t
                    .Skip(1)
                    .Aggregate(
                        new { s = x > 56 ? (x - 57).ToString() : (x - 47).ToString(), o = x > 56 ? 1 : 0 }, 
                        (r, c) => new { s = (char)(c - 48 + r.o + (c + r.o > 57 ? 38 : 48)) + r.s, o = c + r.o > 57 ? 1 : 0 });
                v = (q.o + q.s)
                    .TrimStart('0');
            }
            C.Write(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Windows cmd - 68 chars

```
@set/pd=
:l 
@set/ad=(d+d%%2*(d*5+2))/2&echo %d%&if %d% NEQ 1 goto:l
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript - 68 chars

Unlike the other JS (and most other languages) this one actually adheres to the `->` in the output.

```
for(s='',c=' -> ',i=readline();i>1;i=i%2?i*3+1:i/2)s+=i+c
print(s+1)
```

If we avoid that, this is a **53 char** alternative, prints one number per line:

```
for(p=print,i=readline(),p(i);i>1;)p(i=i%2?i*3+1:i/2)
```

Meant to run with SpiderMonkey:

```
echo 21 | js thisfile.js

21 -> 64 -> 32 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

### MATLAB 7.8.0 (R2009a): 58 characters

```
n=input('');while n>1,n=n/2+rem(n,2)*(n*5+2)/2;disp(n);end
```

Test case:

```
>> n=input('');while n>1,n=n/2+rem(n,2)*(n*5+2)/2;disp(n);end
21
    64
    32
    16
     8
     4
     2
     1
```

Comment: Hey gnovice, we can avoid the `disp(n)`, with: `n=input('');while n>1,n=n/2+rem(n,2)*(n*5+2)/2,end` --- **50 characters!*

Comment: @Jacob: Yeah, that would work. But I was trying to stay *reasonably* close to a decently formatted output like the question has. ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Fortran: 71 chars

```
n=1
1 if(n==1)read*,n
n=merge(n/2,3*n+1,mod(n,2)==0)
print*,n
goto1
end
```

---

Because someone had to do it :)

The count includes required newlines. Fully conformant Fortran 95 (and later) code. Includes full I/O, and performs as many times as you want!

*Edit:* one less char using a goto (points for style!)

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, <strike>78</strike> <strike>72</strike> 67 characters

I actually wrote this program about two years ago, after I read about the sequence in a Pickover book. I cleaned it up a bit, and this is the smallest I can make it and still have user input and a nice, readable output:

```
<?$n=fgets(STDIN);while($n!=1){$n=(($n&1)==0)?($n/2):(($n*3)+1);echo"$n\n";}?>
```

One has to assume short tags are enabled, and I'm not so sure that input will work on all consoles. But it works perfectly on my Windows machine.

---

**Update:** By cheating on the math just a little, we can shave off some characters:

```
<?$n=fgets(STDIN);while($n!=1){$n=(($n&1)==0)?$n/2:$n*3+1;echo"$n\n";}?>
```

---

**Update:**

- Given that `$n&1` returns either `1` or `0`, we can take advantage of PHP's loose typedness and remove a couple more characters.
- Also, incorporating Christian's comment below (with a minor alteration to prevent infinite looping), we can remove one more.
- Finally, since PHP scripts don't need a terminating `?>`, we can get rid of yet two more characters:

The end result:

```
<?$n=fgets(STDIN);while($n>1){$n=(!($n&1))?$n/2:$n*3+1;echo"$n\n";}
```

Comment: suggest changing to "while($n>0)" to adhere with the 'Given a positive integer greater than 0" requirements.

Comment: @Christian Close; had to do `while($n>1)` to prevent infinite looping, but good suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript, <strike>67</strike> 56 chars

```
for(a=[i=prompt()];i-1;a.push(i=i%2?i*3+1:i/2));alert(a)
```

Comment: Why waste the chars on `var `?  Also doesn't include the ` -> ` from the output.  Using the ternary instead of the array index will save 3 more chars too.

Comment: ok. i squeezed it even more. The ' -> ' is not really interesting part and most solutions omit it. Just replace `alert(a)` with: `alert(a.join(' -> '))`.

Answer (score 2):

**Ruby, 41 chars**

```
n=gets.to_i
p n=[n/2,n*3+1][n%2]while n>1
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there seems to be a bit of interest with the LOLCODE solution, I thought I'd compare implementations of the two solution approaches (iterative and tail-recursive) in this language.

First, there is the iterative solution at 203 characters:

```
HAI 1.2
    I HAS A n
    GIMMEH n
    IM IN YR l
        VISIBLE n
        BOTH SAEM 1 BIGGR OF 1 n
        O RLY?
            YA RLY
                GTFO
        OIC
        MOD OF n 2
        WTF?
            OMG 0
                n R QUOSHUNT OF n 2
                GTFO
            OMG 1
                n R SUM OF 1 PRODUKT OF 3 n
        OIC
    IM OUTTA YR l
KTHXBYE
```

To give you the gist of what's going on:

- Input is read from STDIN using the `GIMMEH` keyword
- Looping is done between the `IM IN YR <loopname>` and `IM OUTTA YR <loopname>` statements
- `VISIBLE` is used to print to STDOUT
- The `O RLY?`, `YA RLY`, and `OIC` statements handle the conditional If/Then/Else logic
- The `WTF?`, `OMG <expression>`, and `OIC` statements handle the conditional Switch/Case logic
- Assignment is performed using `<variable> R <value>`
- GTFO breaks from a loop or conditional Switch/Case

And then there is the tail-recursive solution which manages to shave off 2 additional characters for a final count of 201:

```
HAI 1.2
    HOW DUZ I c YR n
        VISIBLE n
        DIFFRINT 1 BIGGR OF 1 n
        O RLY?
            YA RLY
                MOD OF n 2
                WTF?
                    OMG 0
                        c QUOSHUNT OF n 2
                        GTFO
                    OMG 1
                        c SUM OF 1 PRODUKT OF 3 n
                OIC
        OIC
    IF U SAY SO
    I HAS A i
    GIMMEH i
    c i
KTHXBYE
```

Differences here are the definition of a function between the `HOW DUZ I <funcname> YR <args>` and `IF U SAY SO` statements.  Functions are called with `<funcname> <args>`.

Comment: @Earlz I wanted to show the code in it's minimal-character form (without indentation) but what the heck, I'll add it in. :)

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```
def collatz(n):
    if (n%2) == 0:
        return n/2
    else:
        return 3*n+1
def do_collatz(n):
    while n > 1:
        print n
        n = collatz(n)
    print n
do_collatz(int(input("Start number: ")))
```

Not vulnerable to stack overflows, but does not terminate on a sequence that does not converge on 1.
(edit: forgot the input part)

Comment: Well done Raceimaztion, now as a bonus challenge, simply prove that your program always terminates, or find an example where it doesn't.

Comment: @jsn, maybe I should make a code golf to find the number where it doesn't and see the people suffer :)

Comment: @Earlz That would be more like a "proof golf".

Comment: I once read about a professor who puts such unsolved problems as questions on his final exams for some advanced class, and every once in a rare while a student solved one...

Comment: There is no such number that would not converge to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Perl, 59 characters:

```
sub c{print my$x="@_\n";@_=$x&1?$x*3+1:$x/2,goto&c if$x!=1}
```

Answer (score 1):

**VB.Net**, about 180 characters

```
Sub Main()
    Dim q = New Queue(Of Integer)
    q.Enqueue(CInt(Console.ReadLine))
    Do
        q.Enqueue(CInt(If(q.Peek Mod 2 = 0, q.Dequeue / 2, q.Dequeue * 3 + 1)))
        Console.WriteLine(q.Peek)
    Loop Until q.Peek = 1
End Sub
```

funny thing is converting this code into c# create more characters

to make it work in an empty .vb file (about 245 characters)

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System
Module m
    Sub Main()
        Dim q = New Queue(Of Integer)
        q.Enqueue(CInt(Console.ReadLine))
        Do
            q.Enqueue(CInt(If(q.Peek Mod 2 = 0, q.Dequeue / 2, q.Dequeue * 3 + 1)))
            Console.WriteLine(q.Peek)
        Loop Until q.Peek = 1
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Can you actually do away with the `Import` statements and the class around `Main`? Can I type this in notepad and `vbc` will eat it?

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes, What I do is create an empty console program and paste that in and it work. I didn't try what you said.

Comment: that's what I suspected. VS hides a lot away in project files somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Bash, 130 including spaces and newlines:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $1 == 1 ]; then echo $1
else if [ $(($1%2)) == 0 ]; then n=$(($1/2))
else n=$(($1*3+1))
fi
echo "$1 -> `c $n`"
fi
```

This assumes that c is the name of the script file, and it is in the path of the user who's running the script.

Answer (score 1):

### F# 82 Chars

```
let rec f n=printfn "%A" n;if n>1I then if n%2I=0I then f(n/2I)else f(3I*n+1I)
```

Answer (score 1):

**J, 45 characters**

`(-: * 0&=@(2&|)) + (1 + 3&*) * -.@(0&=@(2&|))`

I'm no expert in J. Since the function for mean is +/%#, I'm sure this can be made shorter.

Comment: I like how the program starts with a smile :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Microsoft [Small Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ff384126.aspx)

```
TextWindow.Write( "Number: " )
n = TextWindow.ReadNumber()
TextWindow.Write( "Results: " )
While ( n > 1 )
  TextWindow.Write( n + " -> " )
  If Math.Remainder( n, 2 ) = 0  Then
    n = n / 2
  Else
    n = n * 3 + 1
  EndIf 
EndWhile
TextWindow.WriteLine(1)
```

You can run it at: 
http://smallbasic.com/program/?ZZR544

Answer (score 1):

## GW-BASIC - 54 chars

```
1INPUT N
2N=(N+(N*5+2)*(N MOD 2))/2:?N:IF N>1GOTO 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on ar's code, here's a perl version which actually conforms to the output requirements

```
perl -E 'print"Number: ";$_=<STDIN>;chomp;print"Results: $_";$_=$_%2?$_*3+1:$_/2,print" -> ",$_ while$_!=1;say""'
```

Length: 114 counting the perl invocation and quotes, 104 withouit

I'm sure some experienced golfer can reduce this crude version further.

Answer (score 0):

C#, 88 chars I think.  Recursive

```
void T(int i,string s){Console.Write("{0}{1}",s,i);if(i!=1)T(i%2==0?i/2:(i*3)+ 1,"->");}
```

Plus this initial call

```
T(171, "");
```

Here is a non-recursive method, 107 chars I think

```
void T2(int i){string s="";while(i>=1){Console.Write("{0}{1}",s,i);i=i==1?-1:i=i%2==0?i/2:(i*3)+1;s="->";}}
```

Comment: Plus using statements, plus a class definition, plus a Main method, plus a Console.ReadLine call, plus an int.Parse or long.Parse or ulong.Parse call. You need a *full* program with *full* user *input* and output..

Answer (score 0):

**C++ <strike>113</strike> <strike>100</strike> 95**

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int i){for(std::cin>>i;i>1;i=i&1?i*3+1:i/2)std::cout<<i<<" -> ";}
```

Comment: It may not be too standard but doing `#include <iostream.h>` is suppose to translate to `#include <iostream> \n using namespace std;`

Comment: Yeah -- I considered that, but none of the compilers I normally use has an `<iostream.h>` any more...

Answer (score 0):

### Miranda (101 characters)

```
c n=" 1",if n=1
   =" "++shownum(n)++c(n*3+1),if n mod 2=1
   =" "++shownum(n)++c(n div 2),otherwise
```

(whitespace is syntactically important)

Answer (score 0):

### Powershell : 80 characters

One-liner:

```
"Results: $(for($x=read-host Number;1%$x;$x=@($x/2;3*$x+1)[$x%2]){""$x ->""}) 1"
```

Pretty-printed:

```
"Results: $( for( $x = read-host Number; 1%$x; $x = @( $x/2; 3*$x+1 )[ $x%2 ] )
             { 
                 ""$x ->"" 
             }
           ) 1"
```

#### Without input prompt and output formatting - **44** characters:

```
for($x=read-host;1%$x;$x=@($x/2;3*$x+1)[$x%2]){$x}1
```

Comment: PS Z:\> for($x=read-host;1%$x;$x=@($x/2;3*$x+1)[$x%2]){$x}1
0
Attempted to divide by zero.
At line:1 char:20
+ for($x=read-host;1%$ <<<< x;$x=@($x/2;3*$x+1)[$x%2]){$x}1
1

Answer (score 0):

**VBScript: 105 Characters**

Apparently I'm a glutton for punishment.

```
c(InputBox("?"))
Public Sub c(i)
msgbox(i)
If i>1 Then
If i mod 2=0 Then
c(i/2)
Else
c(3*i+1)
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Factor**:

without golfing

```
USE: math
: body ( n -- n ) >integer dup . "->" . dup odd? = [ 3 * 1 + ] [ 2 / ] if ;
: hailstone ( n --  ) dup 1 > [ body hailstone ] [ . ] if  ;
21 hailstone
```

golfed:

```
21 [ dup 1 > ] [ >integer dup . "->" . dup 2 mod 1 = [ 3 * 1 + ] [ 2 / ] if ] while .
```

Output:

```
21
"->"
64
"->"
32
"->"
16
"->"
8
"->"
4
"->"
2
"->"
1
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP. 69 Characters

Thanks to Danko Durbić for the fgets(STDIN), hope you dont mind :)

```
<?$i=fgets(STDIN);while($i!=1){echo ($i=$i%2?$i*3+1:$i/=2),"\r\n";}?>
```

Comment: As with above, suggest changing to while($1>0)

Answer (score 0):

### bash 57/61/60

Another bash entry. Does not perform infinite precision math, and it may overflow.

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$1;echo $x;((x>1))&&$0 $((x%2?x*3+1:x/2))
```

A version that should not overflow could be

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$1;echo $x;((x>1))&&exec $0 $((x%2?x*3+1:x/2))
```

(edit) An iterative version as well:

```
#!/bin/bash
for((x=$1;x>1;x=x%2?x*3+1:x/2));do echo $x;done
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, 61 <s>70</s> character with input

Iterative, precision depends on JS limits

```
var i=prompt('');while(i>1){console.log(i);i=(i%2)?3*i+1:i/2}
```

Comment: Can get it to 55 symbols with `alert` instead of `console.log`, but usability will suffer.

Comment: Save 4 to remove `var ` and save more chars with `for(i=prompt();i>1;i=i%2?3*i+1:i/2)` removing the braces too... However - your code doesn't print the final `1` or include the `->`

Answer (score 0):

### C: 63 chars

```
main(x){scanf("%d",&x);while(x>printf("%d ",x=x&1?3*x+1:x/2));}
```

This is based on an answer from KennyTM. The for loop was chaged to a while loop and the code brought inside the while.

Answer (score 0):

### Go, 130 characters

```
package main
import(."os"
."strconv")
func main(){n,_:=Atoi(Args[1])
println(n)
for n>1{if n%2!=0{n=n*3+1}else{n/=2}
println(n)}}
```

**Example**

```
./collatz 3
3
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Fortran - 60 Chars

```
read*,n
1 if(n/2*2<n)n=6*n+2
n=n/2
print*,n
if(n>1)goto1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Erlang, 120 chars

```
-module (f).
-export ([f/1]).
f(1)->1;
f(N)->
    io:format("~p ",[N]),
    if N rem 2 =:= 0
        ->f(trunc(N/2));
        true->f(3*N+1)
end.
```

test:

```
f:f(171).

171 514 257 772 386 193 580 290 145 436 218 109 328 164 82 41 124 62 31 94 47 
142 71 214 107 322 161 484 242 121 364 182 91 274 137 412 206 103 310 155 466 
233 700 350 175 526 263 790 395 1186 593 1780 890 445 1336 668 334 167 502 251 
754 377 1132 566 283 850 425 1276 638 319 958 479 1438 719 2158 1079 3238 1619 
4858 2429 7288 3644 1822 911 2734 1367 4102 2051 6154 3077 9232 4616 2308 1154 
577 1732 866 433 1300 650 325 976 488 244 122 61 184 92 46 23 70 35 106 53 160 
80 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Josl - 58 characters**

This version will not stack overflow due to tail recursion.

```
c dup println dup 1 > if dup odd? if 3 * 1+ else 2 / end c
```

Use:

```
main 21 c
```

Or, other examples:

```
main 
  21 c
  63,728,127 c
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure - 70 chars

```
((fn[n](prn n)(if(> n 1)(recur(if(odd? n)(+(* 3 n)1)(/ n 2)))))(read))
```

Or, with proper whitespace and indentation:

```
((fn [n]
  (prn n)
  (if (> n 1)
    (recur
      (if (odd? n)
        (+ (* 3 n) 1)
        (/ n 2)))))
  (read))
```

`recur` forces Clojure to use tail call recursion, so no stack overflows. Works with arbitrarily big numbers. Includes input and output, although it will crash if you enter a non-number :).

Note: shortly after posting my answer I noticed another Clojure implementation with pretty much the same algorithm. However, since that one doesn't attempt to be short, I'll leave my answer here, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

### Grooovy - 59 chars

```
int n=args[0] as int
while(n>1){println n=n%2==0?n/2:n*3+1}
```

Example

```
$ ./collatz.groovy 5
16
8
4
2
1
```

---

With prettier output (**66 chars**)

```
int n=args[0] as int
while(n>1){print " -> ${n=n%2==0?n/2:n*3+1}"}
```

Example

```
$ ./collatz.groovy 5
-> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

### J, 31 characters

```
-:`(>:@(3&*))`1:@.(1&=+2&|)^:a:
```

Usage:

```
-:`(>:@(3&*))`1:@.(1&=+2&|)^:a: 9
9 28 14 7 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

### Common Lisp, <strike>76</strike> 74 chars

```
(defun c(n)(if (eql n 1)'(1)(cons n(if(oddp n)(c(1+(* 3 n)))(c(/ n 2))))))
```

or, written properly,

```
(defun collatz (n)
  (if (eql n 1)
      '(1)
    (cons n (if (oddp n)
                (collatz (1+ (* 3 n)))
                (collatz (/ n 2))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Smalltalk, 103 characters

```
[:n||l|l:=OrderedCollection with:1.[n>1]whileTrue:[l addLast:n.n:=n odd ifTrue:[3*n+1]ifFalse:[n/2]].l]
```

Call by sending it the message #value: with the desired parameter:

```
[:n||l|l:=OrderedCollection with:1.[n>1]whileTrue:[l addLast:n.n:=n odd ifTrue:[3*n+1]ifFalse:[n/2]].l] value: 123
```

Or, more sanely:

```
[:n | | result |
        result := OrderedCollection with: 1.
        [n > 1] whileTrue: [
                result addLast: n.
                n := n odd ifTrue: [3*n + 1] ifFalse: [n / 2]].
        result] value: 123
```

(The Proper Way would be to define the above as a method on Integer so you'd say "123 collatz", rather than as an anonymous closure.)

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby 55 chars

```
n=gets.to_i
while(n>1) do n=((n%2)==1)?3*n+1:n/2;p n end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl, 59 Chars

```
$n=shift;for($i=1;$n>1;$i++){$n=$n%2==0?$n/2:$n*3+1;printf"%002s: %s\n",$i,$n;}
```

However, I like this version at 79 chars (not counting whitespace) better because it prints the line number and the iteration value:

```
$n = shift; for($i = 1; $n > 1; $i++){ $n = $n % 2 == 0 ? $n / 2 : $n*3 + 1; printf "%002s: %s\n", $i, $n;}

$n = shift; 

for($i = 1; $n > 1; $i++){ 
    $n = $n % 2 == 0 ? $n / 2 : $n*3 + 1; 
    printf "%002s: %s\n", $i, $n;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Using an extension of [HQ9+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HQ9%2B) (that I haven't written yet), called HQ9+C where C prints the Collatz Sequence on a number taken from stdin.

```
C
```

:P

Comment: Why does someone do this every code golf? It was funny **once**.

Comment: I'm sorry that I haven't memorized the entirety of StackOverflow like you apparently have.

Comment: Some [] jokes are funny once. Do it once, you're a wit; do it twice you're a half-wit. -Robert Heinlein in the voice of Manny