# The Collatz Sequence problem

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to solve this problem, its not a homework question, its just code I'm submitting to uva.onlinejudge.org so I can learn better java trough examples. Here is the problem sample input :

```
 3 100
 34 100
 75 250
 27 2147483647
 101 304
 101 303
 -1 -1
```

Here is simple output :

```
 Case 1: A = 3, limit = 100, number of terms = 8
 Case 2: A = 34, limit = 100, number of terms = 14
 Case 3: A = 75, limit = 250, number of terms = 3
 Case 4: A = 27, limit = 2147483647, number of terms = 112
 Case 5: A = 101, limit = 304, number of terms = 26
 Case 6: A = 101, limit = 303, number of terms = 1
```

The thing is this has to execute within 3sec time interval otherwise your question won't be accepted as solution, here is with what I've come up so far, its working as it should just the execution time is not within 3 seconds, here is code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    int start;
    int limit;
    int terms;
    int a = 0;

    while (stdin.hasNext()) {
      start = stdin.nextInt();
      limit = stdin.nextInt();
      if (start > 0) {
        terms = getLength(start, limit);
        a++;
      } else {
        break;
      }
      System.out.println("Case "+a+": A = "+start+", limit = "+limit+", number of terms = "+terms);
    }
  }

  public static int getLength(int x, int y) {
    int length = 1;
    while (x != 1) {
      if (x <= y) {
        if ( x % 2 == 0) {
          x = x / 2;
          length++;
        }else{
          x = x * 3 + 1;
          length++;
        }
      } else {
        length--;
        break;
      }
    }

    return length;
  }
}
```

And yes here is how its meant to be solved :

An algorithm given by Lothar Collatz produces sequences of integers, and is described as follows:

```
Step 1:
    Choose an arbitrary positive integer A as the first item in the sequence. 
Step 2:
    If A = 1 then stop. 
Step 3:
    If A is even, then replace A by A / 2 and go to step 2. 
Step 4:
    If A is odd, then replace A by 3 * A + 1 and go to step 2.
```

And yes my question is **how can I make it work inside 3 seconds time interval?**

Comment: There's a Java entry here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388254/code-golf-collatz-conjecture ;)

Comment: @KennyTM entry there is way different, mine is working just the benchmark is breached(3 seconds)

Comment: Three seconds on what platform?  Very few things in code execution are fundamentally specified in absolute time values.

Comment: @David Thornley it doesn't say when you're submitting solution, just `JAVA 1.6.0 - Java Sun JDK`, it runs in less than a second localy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Googling I found [this thread](http://online-judge.uva.es/board/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=3049) where a couple of other people have had the same problem and the solution is to use 64-bit arithmetic instead of 32-bit arithmetic.

Try changing `int` to `long` and see if that helps.

Comment: @Mark Byers I didn't know that makes all this difference, runtime is 0.968 sec .. huge difference . thank you

Comment: The difference is that you might run into an infinite loop because you overflow int.

Comment: @Larry can you explain what you mean I don't get it, I don't think I run infinite loop because `while (stdin.hasNext())` when it runs out of input it should stop