# Why does this simple C program hang up?

Tags: c, freeze

```
int getCycleLen(int n){//counts the number of iterations before n=1
    int cycle_len=0;
    while(n!=1){
        if(n%2==0) n/=2; else n=3*n+1;
        cycle_len++;
    }
    return cycle_len;
}
int main(){
    int i,j,n;
    int max_len=0,len;
    i = 1; j = 1000000;//j = a million
    for(n=i;n<=j;n++){
        printf("%d ",n);
        len = getCycleLen(n);
        if(len > max_len)
            max_len=len;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n",i,j,max_len);
}
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and compiling using gcc 5.4. For some reason the program hangs when n of the for loop is 113299. Any suggestions as to why this happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Project Euler Question 14 (Collatz Problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643260/project-euler-question-14-collatz-problem)

Comment: Same as [collatz-sequence.c
](https://gist.github.com/rustyconover/0319ee8d6841b8d5ef39)

Answer (score 3):

This is an integer overflow. Use a `long` for the parameter to `getCycleLen` instead.

You can see this for yourself if you print every value of `n` as you iterate in `getCycleLen`. When the number gets too big to fit in an `int`, it will overflow and become a negative number. The negative numbers will then not converge on 1.

Answer (score 0):

In C, integers have a specific limit. This limit depends on the architecture of your system. But basically your value has overflowed the the max possible value stored at an integer.