# SIGSEGV "3n + 1"

Tags: c++

`100 - The 3n + 1` problem
http://www.spoj.com/problems/PROBTRES/
always i get this >>> runtime error (SIGSEGV) <<< 
why plz help !

Background:
Problems in Computer Science are often classified as belonging to a certain class of problems (e.g., NP, Unsolvable, Recursive). In this problem you will be analyzing a property of an algorithm whose classification is not known for all possible inputs.

The Problem:

Consider the following algorithm:

```
1. input n

2. print n

3. if n = 1 then STOP

4. if n is odd then n = 3n + 1

5. else n = n / 2

6. GOTO 2
```

Given the input 22, the following sequence of numbers will be printed `22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1`

It is conjectured that the algorithm above will terminate (when a 1 is printed) for any integral input value. Despite the simplicity of the algorithm, it is unknown whether this conjecture is true. It has been verified, however, for all integers n such that `0 < n < 1,000,000` (and, in fact, for many more numbers than this.)

Given an input n, it is possible to determine the number of numbers printed (including the 1). For a given n this is called the cycle-length of n. In the example above, the cycle length of 22 is 16.

For any two numbers i and j you are to determine the maximum cycle length over all numbers between i and j.

The Input:
The input will consist of a series of pairs of integers i and j, one pair of integers per line. All integers will be less than 1,000,000 and greater than 0.

You should process all pairs of integers and for each pair determine the maximum cycle length over all integers between and including i and j.

You can assume that no operation overflows a 32-bit integer.

The Output:
For each pair of input integers i and j you should output i, j, and the maximum cycle length for integers between and including i and j. These three numbers should be separated by at least one space with all three numbers on one line and with one line of output for each line of input. The integers i and j must appear in the output in the same order in which they appeared in the input and should be followed by the maximum cycle length (on the same line).

```
Sample Input:
1 10
100 200
201 210
900 1000

Sample Output:
1 10 20
100 200 125
201 210 89
900 1000 174





    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std ;
    long int a[1000001];

    long int F (long int n){
        if(a[n]!=0)
            return a[n];
        else {
            if(n%2 !=0)
                a[n]=F(n*3+1)+1 ; 
            else 
                a[n]=F(n/2)+1 ; 
            return a[n];
        }
    }
    int main(){
        a[1]= 1 ;
        long int i , j , MX , MN , x=0 ;
        while (cin>>i >> j ){
            MX=max(i,j);
            MN=min(i,j);
            for(;MN<=MX;MN++){
                if(x<F(MN))
                    x=F(MN) ; 
        }

        cout<<i<<" "<<j<<" "<<x<<endl; 
        x= 0; 
        }

        return 0 ;
    }
```

what is the difference between this and my code ?!!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1000001
static int result[MAX];
int calculate(unsigned long i);
int main()
{
    unsigned long int i = 0;
    unsigned long int j = 0;
    unsigned long int k = 0;
    int max,x,y;
    result[1] = result[0] = 1;
    while (scanf("%ld",&i)!= EOF)
    {
        scanf("%ld",&j);
        if (i > j)
        {
            x = i;
            y = j;
        }
        else
        {
            x = j;
            y = i;
        }
        max = 0;
        for (k = y; k <= x; k++)
        {
            if (result[k] != 0 && result[k] > max)
                max = result[k];
            else if (calculate(k) > max)
                max = result[k];
        }
        printf("%ld %\ld %d\n",i,j,max);
    }
    return 0;
}
int calculate(unsigned long i)
{
    if (i < MAX && result[i])
        return result[i];
    if ( i % 2 == 1 )
    {
        if (i < MAX)
            return  result[i] = 2+calculate((3*i+1)/2);
        else
            return 2+calculate((3*i+1)/2);
    }
    else
    {
        if( i < MAX)
            return result[i] = 1 + calculate(i / 2);
        else
            return 1 + calculate(i /2 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give meaningful variable names.

Comment: That's a lot of executable space you're taking up with that array.

Comment: That recursion looks suspicious. I suspect you are getting a stack overflow. How about rewriting this iteratively?

Comment: Also, you didn't `#include <algorithm>`.

Comment: You might want to look through [previous solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2388254/179910) to the same problem.

Comment: You can assume that no operation overflows a 32bit integer - you **must not assume** that no operation will overflow 1 million.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check the actual range of values you're getting for `n`, as it might be stepping outside your array `long a[1000001]`.  Also, you might check your recursion depth.  If you recurse too deeply, you'll overflow the stack.

I would consider adding an assert to test n (ie. `assert(n < 1000001)`), and perhaps a recursion depth variable to check your recursion depth as the first steps to diagnosing and debugging this code.  You can find assert in `<cassert>`.